# Gracenote API: Search and fetch contents in specific language

Tags: api, gracenote

I'm wondering if there is a way to get data in specific language when using gracenote series_search or series_fetch methods.

It turns out that using ger field is useless... I still get data in english ...
If someone could help resolving this, that would be great! =)

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current request with a test account that we can replicate with? According to the documentation, you should just be able to add `<LANG>ger</LANG>` to your request XML...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply!
Here's my request example:
<query CMD="SERIES_SEARCH">
<mode/>
<TEXT type="TITLE">The good wife</TEXT>
<OPTION>
<PARAMETER>select_extended</PARAMETER><VALUE>image</VALUE></OPTION></query>
<auth>
<client>XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</client>
<user>XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</user></auth><lang>fra</lang>

Comment: Have you tried uppercase LANG? And make sure you close the query tag

Comment: This doesn't work either... I'll give it a try tomorrow again... :( Maybe it's the language iso3 name that is unrecognised: <QUERY CMD="SERIES_SEARCH"><MODE/><TEXT type="TITLE">The good wife</TEXT><OPTION><PARAMETER>select_extended</PARAMETER><VALUE>image</VALUE></OPTION></QUERY><auth><CLIENT>xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</CLIENT><USER>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</USER></auth><COUNTRY>france</COUNTRY><LANG>fra</LANG>"

Comment: In fact, it was the damn language name that was not correct! "fre" is the value that should be used. It would be great if gracenote documentation could be a bit more specific... Anyway, thanks for your support =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracenote uses 3-letter ISO 639-2 codes to specify languages. The format is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes - Gracenote supports most major languages.

Thanks to your suggestion, we've added this documentation to our page at: https://developer.gracenote.com/eyeq